# String replacement with dictionary, complications with punctuation

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, punctuation

I'm trying to write a function process(s,d) to replace abbreviations in a string with their full meaning by using a dictionary. where s is the string input and d is the dictionary. For example:

```
>>>d = {'ASAP':'as soon as possible'}
>>>s = "I will do this ASAP.  Regards, X"
>>>process(s,d)
>>>"I will do this as soon as possible.  Regards, X"
```

I have tried using the split function to separate the string and compare each part with the dictionary.

```
def process(s):
    return ''.join(d[ch] if ch in d else ch for ch in s)
```

However, it returns me the same exact string.  I have a suspicion that the code doesn't work because of the full stop behind ASAP in the original string.  If so, how do I ignore the punctuation and get ASAP to be replaced?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it with a single regex:

```
In [24]: d = {'ASAP':'as soon as possible', 'AFAIK': 'as far as I know'}

In [25]: s = 'I will do this ASAP, AFAIK.  Regards, X'

In [26]: re.sub(r'\b' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r'\b', lambda m: d[m.group(0)], s)
Out[26]: 'I will do this as soon as possible, as far as I know.  Regards, X'
```

Unlike versions based on `str.replace()`, this observes word boundaries and therefore won't replace abbreviations that happen to appear in the middle of other words (e.g. "etc" in "fetch").

Also, unlike most (all?) other solutions presented thus far, it iterates over the input string just once, regardless of how many search terms there are in the dictionary.

Comment: +1 - great point about the abbreviations in other words (did not think of that :) )

Comment: One problem with this solution is that it still has O( dictLength * stringLength ) complexity, since it uses all of the dictionary's keys in the regular expression. By iterating over words in the string, and checking if they exist in the dictionary, you only iterate once over the string, respect words in the input boundary, and have O( stringLength ) complexity (see my answer below)

Comment: @RyanMadsen: That's not correct. With any half-decent regex engine the cost of matching a regex of this form is independent of the number of `OR` terms. I recommend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Regular_grammars and links therefrom.

Comment: @NPE You are right. However, there are still other costs to consider. Compiling the regex into a DFA has its own complexity, and the resulting structure (which presumably mimics a trie) incurs additional space requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
def process(s,d):
    for key in d:
        s = s.replace(key,d[key])
    return s
```

Comment: One problem - if both 'AS' and 'ASAP' are keys in d, then 'AS' may get evaluated first, but wrongly replace the leading 'AS' of 'ASAP' in the source text. I think you'll need to modify this code slightly to go through d in reverse order of key length, easily enough done by changing `for key in d` to `for key in sorted(d, key=lambda x:len(x), reverse=True):`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution: use [re.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split), and split by word boundaries (preserving the interstitial characters):

```
''.join( d.get( word, word ) for word in re.split( '(\W+)', s ) )
```

One significant difference that this code has from Vaughn's or Sheena's answer is that this code takes advantage of the O(1) lookup time of the dictionary, while their solutions look at every key in the dictionary. This means that when `s` is short and `d` is very large, their code will take significantly longer to run. Furthermore, parts of words will still be replaced in their solutions: if `d = { "lol": "laugh out loud" }` and `s="lollipop"` their solutions will incorrectly produce `"laugh out loudlipop"`.

Answer (score 1):

use regular expressions:

```
re.sub(pattern,replacement,s)
```

In your application:

```
ret = s
for key in d:
    ret = re.sub(r'\b'+key+r'\b',d[key],ret)
return ret
```

\b matches the beginning or end of a word. Thanks Paul for the comment

Comment: See my comment to Vaughn Cato for the weakness of just iterating over d. Or, since you are using regexen, you could skip the sort and change your code to `ret = re.sub(r'\b'+key+r'\b', d[key],ret)`, so that you don't accidentally replace a smaller acronym found within a larger one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting by spaces, use:

```
split("\W")
```

It will split by anything that's not a character that would be part of a word.

Answer (score 0):

This is string replacement as well (+1 to @VaughnCato). This uses the `reduce` function to iterate through your dictionary, replacing any instances of the keys in the string with the values. `s` in this case is the accumulator, which is reduced (i.e. fed to the replace function) on every iteration, maintaining all past replacements (also, per @PaulMcGuire's point above, this replaces keys starting with the longest and ending with the shortest).

```
In [1]: d = {'ASAP':'as soon as possible', 'AFAIK': 'as far as I know'}

In [2]: s = 'I will do this ASAP, AFAIK.  Regards, X'

In [3]: reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, d[y]), sorted(d, key=lambda i: len(i), reverse=True), s)
Out[3]: 'I will do this as soon as possible, as far as I know.  Regards, X'
```

As for why your function didn't return what you expected - when you iterate through `s`, you are actually iterating through the **characters** of the string - not the words. Your version could be tweaked by iterating over `s.split()` (which would be a list of the words), but you then run into an issue where the punctuation is causing words to not match your dictionary. You can get it to match by importing `string` and stripping out `string.punctuation` from each word, but that will remove the punctuation from the final string (so regex would be likely be the best option if replacement doesn't work).

Comment: You could compare with `word.strip(string.punctuation)`, but operate with `word`.

Comment: @BrendenBrown That's what I was toying around with at first, but I couldn't find a good way of 'knowing' what was stripped out (since you'd have to pull the stripped string from the dictionary, but would need to somehow rejoin it with the punctuation you stripped). However I'm not an expert, so I could definitely be overlooking something :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2

    [s.replace(i,v) for i,v in d.items()]
```