# Python regex susbstitution function to evaluate literal characters

Tags: python, regex

I am developing an application where I need to search and substitute strings in a body of text.

I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814330/string-replacement-with-dictionary-complications-with-punctuation) and have been using the 3rd answer as the basis of my function.

My code looks like:

```
subs_dict = {
    "INT.": "Internet",
    ...
}

def substitutions(self, text):
    return re.sub(
        r'\b' + '|'.join(subs_dict.keys())
        + r'\b', lambda m: subs_dict[m.group(0)],
        text
    )
```

However, this gets tripped up by text such as `"The INTREPID explorer"` which fails with a `Key Error` for `INTR`.

The problem is that in the comparison "INT." gets interpreted as "INT" and any other character as the period is special.

I have temporarily fixed the issue using this modified code:

```
def substitutions(text):
    return re.sub(
        r'\b' + '|'.join(subs_dict.keys()).replace('.', [.])
        + r'\b', lambda m: subs_dict[m.group(0)],
        text
    )
```

Which allows the period to be evaluated literally but maintains the integrity of the dict keys (as opposed to using "INT[.]" as the key which will fail.

However, this has a bad smell to it and of course only takes care of the period, and not any other special characters.

So, I guess my question would be if there is a better way which works and evaluates any special characters literally.

Comment: By the way, if you really do need the `\b` assertions, then I think you need to add brackets. I don't know Python very well; but in all the regex flavours I know, `|` is a low-precedence operator, so the expression above would be equivalent to `(?:\bINT.)|...`. You probably wanted `\b(?:Int.|...)\b`. And if you do make this change then you probably can't just write `r'\b(?:' + ...`, because `\b(:` isn't a valid regex; you might have to write `r'\b' + ('(:' + '|'.join(subs_dict.keys()).replace('.', [.]) + ')') + r'\b'`. And also make the change suggested by thefourtheye, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleaner way would be to escape the actual strings, with [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) before you join them, like this

```
r'\b' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, subs_dict)) + r'\b'
```

For example,

```
>>> import re
>>> subs_dict = {"INT.": "Internet"}
>>> def substitutions(text):
...     return re.sub(r'\b' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, subs_dict)) + r'\b',
...                   lambda m: subs_dict[m.group(0)], text)
... 
>>> substitutions("The INTREPID explorer")
'The INTREPID explorer'
>>> substitutions("The INT.EPID explorer")
'The InternetEPID explorer'
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that does seem better. One issue I'm still having is with trailing spaces. For example where, "The INT.EPID explorer" will get substituted, "The INT. EPID explorer" won't.

Comment: Just remove the `\b`s and try